# Java code shows no errors, but JFrame won't show

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I have a project due in a couple days, and my code in Eclipse shows no errors, and no warnings, how ever the game(JFrame) wont show up. I believe the error has to do with the way I've done the movement

```
this.addKeyListener(movement);
```

Any ideas are welcome!

Main.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable {
private Movement movement = new Movement();

public int width = 800;
public int height = 600;
public int fps = 1000;
public int score;
public int charX;
public int charY;
public int charUp;
public int charDown;
public int charLeft;
public int charRight;
public int movementSpeed = 5;
public int movementFrame = 0;
public int movementDiagonal = 10;

public boolean bCharUp = false;
public boolean bCharDown = false;
public boolean bCharLeft = false;
public boolean bCharRight = false;

public Color cytoplasm = new Color(50,130,255);

public Image character;

public Thread game;

//Double Buffer
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

public Main() {
    //Images
    ImageIcon characterImage = new ImageIcon("F:/workplace/com.thecellsells.lysosome/src/com/thecellsells/lysosome/Lysosome.gif");
    character = (characterImage.getImage());

    //Game Properties
    setSize(width, height);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(cytoplasm);
    this.addKeyListener(movement);


    //Threads
    game = new Thread(this);
    game.start();

    //Other
    charY = height/2 - 10;
    charX = width/2 - 16;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //Double Buffer
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);


}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(character, charX, charY, this);
    repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Main Main = new Main();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        fpsSetter();
    }
}

//FPS -- set's how fast game runs
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void fpsSetter() {
    try {
        game.sleep(fps/fps);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Movement.java

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Movement extends Main implements KeyListener {
public int charUp;
public int charDown;
public int charLeft;
public int charRight;
public int movementSpeed = 5;
public int movementFrame = 0;
public int movementDiagonal = 10;

public boolean bCharUp = false;
public boolean bCharDown = false;
public boolean bCharLeft = false;
public boolean bCharRight = false;
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W ) {

        bCharUp = true;
        if (bCharUp) {
            charY -= 1;
        }
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        bCharLeft = true;
        if (bCharLeft) {
            charX -=1;
        }
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W ) {
        bCharDown = true;
        if (bCharDown) {
            charY -=1;
        }
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        bCharRight = true;
        if (bCharRight) {
            charX +=1;
        }
    }

}
@Override
public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W ) {
        bCharUp = false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        bCharLeft = false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        bCharDown = false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        bCharRight = false;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }        
}
```

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `setPreferredSize(width, height);`.

EDIT:
The problem lies in that you extended the Main class in the Movement class. So when you start the program, the movement class calls the Main class and that initializes the Movement class again, making a race condition. Just dont extend the Main class and make variables `charX` and `charY` static. Thus you can access the variables anywhere using Main..

Comment: Thanks, darkprince! I removed `extends main` and made the `charX` and `charY` `public int static`, fixing the  `JFrame`; however now my charcacter wont show up. Looking into it ATM.

Comment: I figured it out! I feel stupid :(

I was using a different computer originally, and the file is in a different location. Oops!

Answer (score 0):

In your main() method, you are creating the Main object (which extends from JFrame) but you haven't set it visible.